# Importing React Components and Images with require()

Tags: reactjs

In React, what are the differences between loading an image vs. loading a component using **require()**?

When I load an image using **require("image path")**, it works. When I load a React component using **require("component")** I get an error.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Answer (score 0):

For images in React, You need to require

```js
<img src={require('../assests/logo.png')} />
```

But it is totally different case with components. **You import React components bases on how you exported**.

*And use ES6 to import and export in reactjs*

And there are two types of exports

**Named Export**

Named exports are useful to export several values at ones. During the import, it is important to use the same name.

```js
// how to export
export function myfunc() {}

// how to import
import { myfunc } from './myfile';
```

**Default export.**

Default exports are useful to export only a single value. During the import, able to omit the curly bares and use any name.

```js
// how to export
default export function() {}

// how to import
import anynameyouwant from './myfile';
```